# Coral.ai Dev Board: ValueError: Failed to load delegate from libedgetpu.so.1

Tags: google-coral

Installed Coral Dev Board from scratch in accordance with the manual (https://www.coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/) Successsfully started the Demo using the command `edgetpu_demo --stream` but only once. upon repeating I receive this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 160, in load_delegate
    delegate = Delegate(library, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 119, in __init__
    raise ValueError(capture.message)
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/edgetpu_detect_server", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('edgetpuvision==7.0', 'console_scripts', 'edgetpu_detect_server')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/detect_server.py", line 33, in main
    run_server(add_render_gen_args, render_gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/apps.py", line 43, in run_server
    camera = make_camera(args.source, next(gen), args.loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/detect.py", line 128, in render_gen
    interpreters, titles = utils.make_interpreters(args.model)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/utils.py", line 52, in make_interpreters
    interpreter = edgetpu.make_interpreter(model_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycoral/utils/edgetpu.py", line 87, in make_interpreter
    delegates = [load_edgetpu_delegate({'device': device} if device else {})]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycoral/utils/edgetpu.py", line 52, in load_edgetpu_delegate
    return tflite.load_delegate(_EDGETPU_SHARED_LIB, options or {})
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 163, in load_delegate
    library, str(e)))
ValueError: Failed to load delegate from libedgetpu.so.1
```

Same error when trying other demo models.After reboot, it works again once but fails upon second execution. Running as sudo changes output to

```
mendel@red-llama:~/coral$ sudo edgetpu_demo --stream
Press 'q' to quit.
Press 'n' to switch between models.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Further Info:

```
mendel@red-llama:~$ ls -la /dev/apex_0
crw-rw---- 1 root apex 120, 0 Feb 14  2019 /dev/apex_0

mendel@red-llama:~/coral/coral/pycoral$ lspci
0000:00:00.0 PCI bridge: Synopsys, Inc. DWC_usb3 (rev 01)
0000:01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
0001:00:00.0 PCI bridge: Synopsys, Inc. DWC_usb3 (rev 01)
0001:01:00.0 System peripheral: Device 1ac1:089a


mendel@red-llama:~/coral/coral/pycoral$ lspci -nnk
0000:00:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Synopsys, Inc. DWC_usb3 [16c3:abcd] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
0000:01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Kernel driver in use: hif_pci
    Kernel modules: wlan
0001:00:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Synopsys, Inc. DWC_usb3 [16c3:abcd] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
0001:01:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Device [1ac1:089a]
    Subsystem: Device [1ac1:089a]
    Kernel driver in use: apex
    Kernel modules: apex

mendel@red-llama:~/coral$ groups mendel
mendel : mendel adm sudo audio video plugdev staff games users netdev input render bluetooth i2c systemd-journal apex
```

I am stuck here using the usual resources. Thanks for any help.

Edit:

It seems that one Process is not releasing a resource properly:

```
Nov 24 16:24:51 red-llama kernel: [  252.454215] apex 0001:01:00.0: Process 4034 is opening a node held by 3955.
Nov 24 16:33:50 red-llama kernel: [  791.756410] apex 0001:01:00.0: Process 4058 is opening a node held by 3955.
Nov 24 17:01:00 red-llama kernel: [ 2421.531004] apex 0001:01:00.0: Process 4123 is opening a node held by 3955.
Nov 24 17:29:32 red-llama kernel: [ 4133.521441] apex 0001:01:00.0: Process 4447 is opening a node held by 4346.
```

Edit 2:
I tried with being connected over the USB conncetion (`mdt shell` command) and SSH from a different machine. Same behaviour.

Also I tried `sudo edgetpu_demo --stream` and `sudo edgetpu_demo --device` Also no difference regarding the behavior.

Edit 3:

Did

```
mendel@red-llama:~$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep libedgetpu.so.1
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Path `/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    libedgetpu.so.1 -> libedgetpu.so.1.0
```

IMHO it looks like the code is loading an "old" version. If I understand the versioning right, *so.1.0 is newer than *.so.1.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this with the help of Google Support: If I stop the script with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>, the scripts can be restarted with no problems.

Comment: Good find my man. Works for me!

Comment: In my case, I had nothing to stop, but I had some background python3 processes. `sudo pkill python3` is what worked for me! Thanks for the insight!